# Angular Directive not showing in ng-Switch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have 4 templates being shown based upon var.type. I have 2/4 showing properly, but for some reasons 2 of them are not rendering anything. In the HTML I see the switch being properly activated, but the directive isn't being placed inside as expected.

```js
angular.module('lodgicalWebApp');

angular.module('lodgicalWebApp')
  .directive('lodReportVariableCgflookup', function () {
    return {
      template: '{{var.name}}<label for="repeatSelect"> {{var.name}} </label> \
       <select name="repeatSelect" ng-model="Vars[var.name]" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="data.repeatSelect"> \
          <option ng-repeat="option in  var.possibleVals" value="{{option.id}}">{{option.name}}</option> \
       </select>',
      restrict: 'EA'
    };

  });


angular.module('lodgicalWebApp')
  .directive('lodReportVariableBoolean', function () {
    return {
      template: '{{var.name}}<input ng-model="Vars[var.name]" type="checkbox" ng-true="{{var.value}}">',
      restrict: 'EA',
      
    };
  });


angular.module('lodgicalWebApp')
  .controller('ReportsCtrl', function ($scope,  $routeParams, LodgicalReportService,  Report) {
    $scope.selectedReport.variables = [
      {name: "Start Date",possibleVals:[],type: "Date", value: "2016-01-18"},
      {name: "Operator",possibleVals: [{id:1,name:"test"},{id:2,name:"thanksStackOverflow"}], type: "CfgLookup"},
      {name: "Include Security Deposits", type: "Boolean", value: "False"}
    ]
  
  });
```

```html
   <div ng-repeat="var in selectedReport.variables">
    <div ng-switch="var.type">
                     <!-- CfgLookup not rendering -->
     <div ng-switch-when="CfgLookup" data-lod-report-variable-cfglookup ></div>
     <div ng-switch-when="Boolean" data-lod-report-variable-boolean></div>
     <div ng-switch-when="Date" data-lod-report-variable-date ></div>
     <div ng-switch-when="CfgLookup-Multi" data-lod-report-variable-cfglookup></div>


    </div>
   </div>
```

This isn't a functioning example, but it should illustrate enough to hopefully shine some light on this major frustration.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I should have noted that it's the CfgLooup and CfgLookup-Multi that are not working. Also for this example the multi and lookup should use the same template.

Comment: You have a typo in your directive name, note the 'cfg' vs 'cgf' in the directive name: `lodReportVariableCgflookup`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo that would surely mess it up:

"data-lod-report-variable-cfglookup" is what you wrote in the HTML code as the directive name, while the directive name in your JS code is "lodReportVariableCgflookup". (cfglookup vs cgflookup)

EDIT: In addition, I noticed that you used the same directive "lodReportVariableCgflookup" on both the directives that you say are not working.

It's possible you have another issue as well, but I'd start with that one :)

Comment: That was it... my code-lexia must me kicking in. Time to step away from the LCD glow for a moment! Thanks for the extra set of eyes to catch the newb mistake. I had to read that over 100 times and didn't catch it.

Comment: As for the same directive, I'm aware and noted that above. Thanks for double checking though :)